# LUKS instruction set when booting GRUB in EFI mixed mode

Tags: linux, grub, uefi, luks

There are [some amd64 computers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom) that only support to boot from **UEFI in x86** (32-bit) mode but allow to [load an amd64 operating system](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI#Support_for_mixed-mode_systems:_64-bit_system_with_32-bit_UEFI). On GNU/Linux that is usually achieved by issuing `--target=i386-efi` when installing the GRUB boot loader.

Nowadays **GRUB** (v2.06) allows to boot Linux from a **LUKS-encrypted** `/boot` partition (even one inside a [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management)) with the `GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y` key and the appropriate LUKS or LUKS2 modules loaded.

If we boot a system with this **32-bit EFI** setup, will LUKS be decrypting the contents of the partition using the full **64-bit** instruction set (and [AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#x86_architecture_processors) when applicable) or will it stick to **32-bit** instructions when the operating system is running?

Answer (score 2):

GRUB will read encrypted partitions in 32-bit mode, i.e. without using accelerated instructions but then it will hand partitions and pass the execution to the Linux kernel which will work in 64-bit mode using x86-64 routines thus it will utilize everything available.

Comment: Are you aware of any documentation with the details on how that's done?

Comment: Nope, sorry, never been interested in that.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer because it's not incorrect per se, however when you said "it will hand everything to the Linux kernel" it was ambiguous enough for me to understand that the key was handed as well, and therefore I cannot mark it as correct.

Comment: I've corrected my answer to remove an uninternational ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

### On Linux LUKS will use the full x64 instruction set

and **on GRUB it will only use 32-bit** instructions as, unlike in OpenBSD where the [bootloader's drive encryption driver](https://man.openbsd.org/softraid) keeps running behind the scenes, GRUB's [cryptodisk](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=grub.git;a=blob;f=grub-core/disk/cryptodisk.c;h=497097394f78c398cf0dc68d8fc6d8c46eab85bd;hb=HEAD) and [LUKS](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup) are **two completely different** implementations that run **separately** at different boot stages and **don't share any information at all** with one another.

According to one of its authors in [this thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2011-04/msg00148.html) from the GRUB developers mailing list

> a) Crypto in GRUB is much less performant than in kernel due to
> inavailability of many accelerated instructions. So prepare for key
> recovery taking considerable time or decrease key strengthening.
>
> b)
> You'll need to enter passphrase twice. Once for GRUB, once for OS.